# What does the <A download> alternative refer to in Google Chrome's "Intent to Deprecate and Remove: Top-frame navigations to data URLs"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, anchor

I am trying to allow a user download a json file from the browser in Google Chrome using anchor tag.

```
<a
id="download_anchor"
href=`data:${downloadState.href}`
download="myjsonfile.json"
>
Download JSON
</a>
```

It works in FireFox, but in Chrome I get an error
`Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/json;charset=utf-8,%7B%22smla%22%3A%22hie%22%2C%22wwoo%22%3A333%7D`

I was led to this document that describes why Chrome is blocking anchor downloads to URLs: [Intent to Deprecate and Remove: Top-frame navigations to data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/GsIAQlemBQAJ)

Thankfully it gives alternatives! :

`The following will still be allowed:` ...

```
    Via non-browser-handled MIME types
    Via <A download>
    Via “Save link as”
```

What do they mean by still allowing `<A download>` ?

*How is the `<A download>` alternative different from my `<A ... download="myfile.json">`?*

I've made a front-end-only app. The "Save link as" seems to work OK, but isn't ideal. I'd like to try out whatever they mean by `<A download>` alternative, but I don't understand how it is different from what I am already doing.

Comment: The former leaves it up to the browser to suggest a file name (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), the latter is _your_ suggested file name.

Comment: so, if I just put 'download' without a suggested filename, then it might work? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, according to MDN, which I tend to trust.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! How can I accept your answer?

Comment: These are comments, not answers. You can always self-answer, although if you do, try to add an example of what you did and maybe why.